# Rails Console Quits when creating 1 million records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bulkinsert

I am trying to construct a logic that allows me to bulk insert a million records into the database using Ruby on Rails 6, PostgreSQL and Docker. To give a bit of a background, I have a `Food` model with the following table:

```
  create_table "foods", force: :cascade do |t|    
    t.string  "name", null: false
    t.string  "type", null: false
    t.datetime "expiration_date", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

In the model, I have the following logic constructed:

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  def self.bulk(record_num)
    self.insert_all(create_records(record_num))
  end

  def self.create_records(record_num)
    record_num.times.map do |num|
      {
        name: "food_#{num}",
        type: "food_type_#{num}",
        expiration_date: rand(1.years.ago..Time.current),
        created_at: Time.current,
        updated_at: Time.current
      }
    end
  end
end
```

I can seed around 200,000 records at ~70 seconds, but when it reaches 300,000 records my postgres server quits and gives me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

I tried resetting the database as well as the docker container but nothing seems to work.
I will also continue searching for options but if anyone could help me find a clue on how to fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Taisei. From the above description I can say, that your server reaching memory limit at some point. Try to perform insertion in batches. You can write it yourself or use one of the existing libraries, e.g. https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert. 
Alternative solution is to construct SQL query with `GENERATE_SERIES()` function.

Comment: Thank you @SergiiK! I reconstructed the logic so that users can pass in the number of records and batch size. In my environment, 10 batches of 100,000 records did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. You have a field called `type` which is a reserved keyword in Rails. This will cause issues when you try to call, for example, `Food.first`:

```
> Food.first
  Food Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "foods".* FROM "foods" ORDER BY "foods"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):5
        1: from (irb):6:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'food_type_0'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Food.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.)
```

best rename it to something like `food_type` instead.

2. I was able to run the code on a MacBook Pro with 16GB of RAM and an M1 chip. This leads me to think your computer is running out of memory during execution. I suspect the problem is that your method uses `.map`, which returns an array of hashes:

```rb
def self.create_records(record_num)
  record_num.times.map do |num|
    {
      name: "food_#{num}",
      type: "food_type_#{num}",
      expiration_date: rand(1.years.ago..Time.current),
    }
  end
end
```

3. No need to call `Time.current` multiple times. Best to store it in a local variable and use that instead.

I think there are two solutions to your problem:

1. Perform the insertion in batches
2. Run the code on a machine with more RAM:

```rb
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  class << self
    def bulk num
      insert_all create_records(num)
    end

    private def create_records(num)
      time = Time.current
      num.times.map do |num|
        {
          name: "food_#{num}",
          food_type: "food_type_#{num}",
          expiration_date: rand(1.year.ago..time),
          created_at: time,
          updated_at: time,
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @DaniG2k. Works like a charm. I was actually trying to find a way to decrease the execution time as it took 350 seconds to do seed in 100000 data. But assigning Time.current decreased it to ~160 seconds. I can't believe I missed something so obvious. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Glad I could help :)